# Placeholder doesn't work in NicEdit

Tags: javascript, textarea, nicedit

I'm using NicEdit Inline WYSIWYG and try to understand how to make placeholder work with it.

I created a div with attribute placeholder, but when NicEdit activate it, show blank textarea without placeholder.

Maybe there is some way to make it work. As I understood it writes text directly into div.

In code it looks like. (I comment display non for textarea)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRvqA.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could manually add/remove the placeholder, by using nicEditor Events.
`focus` Send when an editor gains focus (IE someone clicks inside it).
`blur` Sent when an editor instance loses focus.

```
var editor = new nicEditor();
var $placeholder = '<p>Click here to add content...</p>';

$('[id^="textArea"]').each(function() {
    var textAreaId =  $(this).attr("id");

    editor.addInstance( textAreaId );
    var editorInstance = editor.instanceById(textAreaId)

    // Add the initial Placeholder
    var content = editorInstance.getContent();
    if(content == "" || content == "<br>"){
        editor.instanceById(textAreaId).setContent($placeholder);
    }

    // onFocus - Remove the placeholder
    editor.addEvent('focus', function() 
    {
        if (editorInstance.getContent() == $placeholder){
            editor.instanceById(textAreaId).setContent("<br>");
        }
    });

    // onBlur - Re-add the placeholder
    editor.addEvent('blur', function() 
    {
        var newText = editorInstance.getContent();
        if(newText == "" || newText == "<br>") {
            editor.instanceById(textAreaId).setContent($placeholder);
        }
    });
});
```

Initially, check to see if there is no content or if there is a single `<br>` (this is nicEditor's placeholder). If so, replace with your placeholder.
Then on focus check for the placeholder and change the content back to `"<br>"`.
Then on blur check if the content is still empty and replace it with the placeholder again